asyncio server does not cancels request even if aiohttp.ClientSession exceeds its timeout
The final goal is to cancel request on server side if client exceeds its timeout.
The code related to start the server:
def run_server_loop(
    routes: web.RouteTableDef,
    shutdown_state: ShutdownState,
    logger: Logger,
    *,
    port: int,
    periodic_callback: Callable[[], None] | None = None,
    shutdown_callback: Callable[[], None] | None = None,
) -> None:
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            _run_server(
                routes,
                shutdown_state,
                logger,
                port=port,
                periodic_callback=periodic_callback,
            )
        )
    finally:
        if shutdown_callback is not None:
            shutdown_callback()
        logger.info('Server stopped')
        flush_logs()

async def _run_server(
    routes: web.RouteTableDef,
    shutdown_state: ShutdownState,
    logger: Logger,
    *,
    port: int,
    periodic_callback: Callable[[], None] | None = None,
) -> None:
    try:
        app = web.Application()
        app.add_routes(routes)
        runner = web.AppRunner(
            app,
            access_log_format=(
                '%a %t [%D μs] "%r" %{Content-Length}i %s '
                '%b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"'
            ),
        )
        await runner.setup()
        site = web.TCPSite(runner, port=port)
        await site.start()
        logger.info(f'Listening {site.name}')

        while not shutdown_state.is_shutdown_requested:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            if periodic_callback is not None:
                periodic_callback()

        await runner.cleanup()
    except:  # noqa
        logger.critical('Unhandled exception', exc_info=True)
        raise

Here is my endpoint code:
@routes.get('/ping')
async def handle_ping(_) -> web.Response:
    try:                
        import time
        import asyncio
        for i in range(10):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

        return web.json_response(
            data=PingResult(
                service_name=service_name,
                version=SERVICE_VERSION,
                storage_path=str(storage_dir.path),
                daemon_pid=daemon.pid,
                daemon_status=str(daemon.status.value),
            ).dict()
        )
    except asyncio.CancelledError as ce:
        print('Request was cancelled')
        return HTTPBadRequest(ErrorResult(error='Request was cancelled'))

Client code
async def ping(timeout=10) -> PingResult:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=ClientTimeout(total=timeout)) as session:
        async with session.get('http://localhost:5002/ping') as resp:
            body = await resp.json()
            return PingResult.parse_obj(body)

Models
from aiohttp import web
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ErrorResult(TypedDict):
    error: str


class HTTPBadRequest(web.HTTPBadRequest):
    def __init__(self, error: Mapping) -> None:
        super().__init__(text=dumps(error), content_type='application/json')


class PingResult(BaseModel):
    service_name: str
    version: str
    storage_path: str
    daemon_pid: int
    daemon_status: str

Even if I call ping(timeout=2) I can see that the request on the server wasn't cancelled. Or if I call curl http://localhost:5002/ping and terminate the command in less than 2-3 second I'm getting the same behavior (the server side code works without any termination).
It seems like I'm misunderstanding the whole idea of cancelling request but I can figure out how can I achieve my main goal.

Needs to be enabled explicitly in current versions of aiohttp (you haven't shown the code to run the server): https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#peer-disconnection

@SamBull Could you please write an answer an I'll mark it as the answer. Based on your comment I found out that I had to pass handler_cancellation=True to the web.AppRunner constructor

In current versions of aiohttp, handler cancellation is an opt-in feature (due to it causing issues for developers coming from other frameworks).
It can be enabled by passing handler_cancellation=True to web.run_app() or the AppRunner.
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#peer-disconnection
